# How to properly end Eclipse launch configuration execution?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse plugin contributing a new launch configuration type. It works perfectly expected that when the execution of a launch configuration for this new type is completed, the launch configuration button tooltip still indicates that my configuration is running.

This causes problem when I want to launch several of such configurations using launch groups, the second configuration waits indefinitely for the first one to complete (I am using the wait until termination option from the launch group). So I guess I am missing something to tell the platform that the execution of the launch config is completed.

Comment: Do you have an IProgressMonitor to notify the Launch is done? monitor.done()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you need to start a new system [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) when your launch configuration is launched ([`ILaunchConfigurationDelegate#launch`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2Fmodel%2FILaunchConfigurationDelegate.html)) and then create a [`RuntimeProcess`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2Fmodel%2FRuntimeProcess.html) for this `Process`. The `RuntimeProcess` will then generate the necessary [`DebugEvents`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2FDebugEvent.html) and notify the corresponding [`ILaunch`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2FILaunch.html) when it was terminated.

You will usually create the `RuntimeProcess` by calling [`DebugPlugin#newProcess(ILaunch, Process, String)`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2FDebugPlugin.html) but it is also possible to instantiate it directly (e.g. if you want to extend the class `RuntimeProcess`).

Comment: Ys you ar right. I finally accepted this answer, but thanks to manouti, that helped me to find it myself.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at sample launch configurations (mainly the one provided by the Ant plugin), there is an [`org.eclipse.debug.core.model.ITerminate`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/model/ITerminate.html) interface that is implemented in the process/debug targets that execute in the launch.

A [`org.eclipse.debug.core.IDebugEventSetListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/IDebugEventSetListener.html) is registered to handle terminate events which are triggered by calling the following statement:

```
DebugPlugin.getDefault().fireDebugEventSet(
                  new DebugEvent[] {new DebugEvent(this, DebugEvent.TERMINATE)});
```

Sample code from the `AntLaunchDelegate` class:

```
final boolean[] terminated = new boolean[1];
terminated[0] = launch.isTerminated();
IDebugEventSetListener listener = new IDebugEventSetListener() {
    public void handleDebugEvents(DebugEvent[] events) {
        for (int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            DebugEvent event = events[i];
            for (int j = 0, numProcesses = processes.length; j < numProcesses; j++) {
                if (event.getSource() == processes[j]
                        && event.getKind() == DebugEvent.TERMINATE) {
                    terminated[0] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventListener(listener);
monitor
        .subTask(AntLaunchConfigurationMessages.AntLaunchDelegate_28);
while (!monitor.isCanceled() && !terminated[0]) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
DebugPlugin.getDefault().removeDebugEventListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am not sure to understand your answer. This listener is used to know when to terminate the launch config. In my case, I know exactly what to do, and my problem is that at the end of my launch configuration code, it's still displayed running.

Comment: My starting point was to search for the text "already running" in the Eclipse code (I'm assuming this is the message that the tooltip displays) and it leads me to the class `LaunchingResourceManager` where I can see that the text is added in the `appendLaunched` method. To check if there is an already running launch, it calls `ILaunch[] launches = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunches();` and checks if any `ILaunch` is not terminated. Therefore, the problem could be that there is still an `ILaunch` that is not terminated and registered in the launchManager.

Comment: Thanks, I get your point now. But my problem is why my "launch" is not terminated ?